# Docker not installing packages, error says: sh: webpack: not found

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker, im new to it, it is supposed to  install the packages and then copy them to the docker instance.

But when it runs npm start, it complains that it doesnt find webpack(which is  set as a dependency on package.json) which should have been installed.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.2.0-alpine as dependencies
WORKDIR /app


COPY ./app/package.json /app/package.json
COPY ./app/package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

RUN if [ ! -d /app/node_modules ]; then npm install; else echo "skip install"; fi


FROM node:18.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY app/ /app/

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And this is the folder structure:
[image: folder]

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Why do you think webpack should be installed?

Comment: because its as a dependency on package.json @HansKilian

Comment: Does it exist in the image?  For example, if you `docker run --rm your-image ls /app/node_modules`, is it installed?  What other debugging have you done?